# Does DDL operation commit DML operation which run before DDL?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I have such steps:

1. Insert into tableA
2. Drop tableB
3. Insert into tableC

A) when i do rollback after 3 step does it also rollback step1?
B) procedure D contains these steps. An error occured while runing step 3. Whether step1 is commited?
C) Is there difference between killing session in step 3 vs error in step 3 from view point of transaction?

Answer (score 4):

A) DDL carries an implicit commit, so if these are all happening in the same session then a rollback after Step 3 would only affect Step 3.

B) It is a bad idea to embed DDL commands in a procedure, for exactly this reason. You now have potentially inconsistent data because the procedure isn't - and *can't* be - atomic (a single transaction). At the very least, handle any DDL at the very end where there should be an explicit commit anyway, so that a rollback would correctly handle the entire transaction.

C) No difference in killing vs. error from the point of view of the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a legitimate need to do this drop from PL/SQL (and there usually isn't), you can preserve your transaction by handling this in another proc with autonomous transaction defined:

```
create table tableA (col1 integer);
create table tableB (col1 integer);
create table tableC (col1 integer);

DECLARE
  PROCEDURE pl_drop_table
  IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tableB';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END pl_drop_table;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableA (col1) values (1);

  pl_drop_table;

  INSERT INTO tableC (col1) values ('asdf'); -- will fail

  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK; -- will undo the tableA insert as well.
END;
```

Be aware that to drop that table you can't have any dependency on it in the PL/SQL call stack you are executing. Any reference to it must be in dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) to break the dependency chain.